# Define hash function for typescript class for use as key in dictionary/map

Tags: typescript

What's the idiomatic way to use class object in dictionary keys in Typescript?

For example, I'd like to have a `Point` class defined as such:

```
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}
```

... and then be able to use `Point` object as dictionary key as such:

```
let map: Map<Point, number> = new Map();
```

This above won't work since `Point` is being compared by reference. For example,

```
map.add(new Point(0, 1), 1);
map.add(new Point(0, 1), 2);
console.log(map);
```

... will gives us:

```
Map(2) {
  Point { x: 0, y: 1 } => 1,
  Point { x: 0, y: 1 } => 2 
}
```

Comment: You need to define your own Map (you can extend the native one) that overloads `set()` and `get()` to use your hash. It's not exactly idiomatic but it's the best we currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```js
class Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    hash() {
        return `${this.x},${this.y}`
    }

    static _(x: number, y: number) {
        return new Point(x, y).hash();
    }
}

let map: Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

map.set(Point._(0, 1), 1);
map.set(Point._(0, 1), 2);
console.log(map);
```

Or you could extend Map and override the `set` function

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=18&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gbwFDV9AHgFzTICuAtgEYCmATgNw54CexZVdjTuw8yEqWqWCp4tABRESFGrQA00VtI60AlJm55UAC0QQAdPmgBeAozxbdB5icXm8AXyybtkbePXYLF2tVSlaZGgAAwASDB09Qwc5cMjrB2DNJ00BMFREYGgAfUk2GToFJXZZT00fPwCg5GoAdzgkNEki1X1XCHdVe1wnFJA-aHIwAAdiAFkRgB4BWhQAcwUSugA%20Wxr6ieHpwXnFgtpljy4h4f0IP3EEFFR9XIAGBQBGVSeurBOzi6u0W-EH6GeCgATG9ePx4P19CB4HNxCcukA).